# Facebook and Google+ sharing suddenly stopped working properly in Wordpress

Tags: facebook, social-sharing

I've tried to find the answer to my problem by browsing through similar, older threads here, but I can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

I have sharing buttons for the most common social networks. I've had them forever and all of them always worked. Only that Facebook and Google+ recently stopped working properly and I can't figure out why.

As for the **Facebook** sharing it won't retrieve any information. It will only share my blog's URL without grabbing the title, text or image.
If I copy and paste the URL directly into Facebook to share, the same thing happens.

As for **Google+**, whenever I hit the button I get an error. If I just copy and paste the link into Google+ directly, it will properly receive all the necessary information, though. I guess just finding a different code for the Google+ button itself might do the trick.

Here's [my blog](http://zoomingjapan.com/life-in-japan/foreign-names-in-japan/) (sample blog post where you can see and try the sharing buttons yourself).

My header.php: http://pastebin.com/uype2BET

The code concerning the sharing buttons in my single.php:

```
 <ul class="social_buttons">
 <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
      data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
      data-via="zoomingjapan"
      data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>"
      data-related="zoomingjapan: Admin of Zooming Japan"
      data-count="horizontal"
data-lang="en">Tweet</a></li>
<li> <g:plusone size="medium" callback="plusone_vote"></g:plusone></li>
<li style="margin-left:-10px;">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/facebook-share.jpg" alt="Share this article on Facebook" /></a></li> 
<li style="margin-left:-10px;"><div class="fb-like" id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" show_faces="false" layout="button_count"></fb:like></li>
<li><?php $pinterestimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&media=<?php echo $pinterestimage[0]; ?>&description=<?php the_title(); ?>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">Pin It</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: working fine for me.

Comment: @Roberthue Thanks for the feedback. It only works for some blog entries, but more often than not it doesn't work.

Comment: cab you post a link where it doesn't work

Comment: Pretty much all the newer posts like this one: http://zoomingjapan.com/travel/otaru-snow-light-path-festival/
Facebook share doesn't work at all, but Google+ seems to work.

Comment: Please do not link to outgoing sources. Those can be fade away and the question will be impossible to understand. File an [edit] and fix that pastebin link, please. And please keep that in mind for question nr. 79.